# Copy specific row to another workbook after last row

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook (WB1) with a Sheet (Sheet1) with data (A2:W2).

I want to create a VBA where i can copy a specific row from WB1 and paste it into antoher workbook (WB2 / Sheet2) after the last row.

Can anyone help on that?

Unfortunately I just need a code on that and my tries were not going anywhere

Comment: You should firstly calculate where this last empty row exists: `Dim lastR as Long` `lastR = WB2.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row`. Then copy it in `"A" & latR + 1`...

Answer (score 0):

If both workbook are open you can do it like this.

```
Sub CopyRow()
On Error GoTo Err
    With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1") ' like From ThisWorkbook
        myrow = 4 ' Row to be copied
        colCount = .UsedRange.Columns.Count ' Colums to be copied like From ThisWorkbook
        
        DesRow = "A" & Trim(CStr(Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1-(inBok2)").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1))
        .Range(.Cells(myrow, 1), .Cells(myrow, colCount)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1-(inBok2)").Range(DesRow)
    End With
Exit Sub
Err:
MsgBox ("# Error - Can`t perform the copy. Check sheet names and that bouth workbooks are open.")
End Sub
```